# How determine what the volume is

Tags: hyper-v, ntfs

So, to the point, I've been getting this on a 2016 server hosting hyper v:

```
A corruption was discovered in the file system structure on volume
\\?\Volume{1c63d7ca-0000-0000-0000-f01500000000}. 
The Master File Table (MFT) contains a corrupted file record. 
The file reference number is 0x9000000000009. 
The name of the file is "<unable to determine file name>".
```

I didn't see that volume listed in diskpart, nor in vssadmin list shadows.  I also checked for the GUID for the VHDs for the guests, not there.  I'm thinking it's a vss but I can't fully determine.

Can anyone point me to finding out what that GUID is for?

Comment: Did you try to look in the Event viewer the error to see if it will show you more infromation?